# All Select list options with a class and value not blank using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a select list of times.  Each select option could have a class of class="timeSoldOut" on it or not.  Each select option will have a value of some sort of time, EXCEPT the very first item in the list which is the default "Choose a Time" option.

What I want to do is see if all actual time list items are sold out then I am going to trigger something like "All times sold out" message.

My issue is, since there is one option (the default 'Choose a Time'), that will never have the "timeSoldOut" message on it, I need to know how to loop through all the options to see if the timeslot has a time value AND does not have the "timeSoldOut" class.  I have a $.each() loop set up just looping through all the times list, seems kind of expensive and might not need it. My main goal is to just see if there are not times left and show my message. 
I am having issues because a simple check for all the options that have a value and the class sold out and if there are any that have a value and NOT sold out.
Does that make sense?
I have included what I have so far, HTML and the jQuery.

jQuery

```
  var productShowTimeListOption = $('#ShowTimeList option');
   var productTimeSlotSoldOut = $(".timeSoldOut");
  //If option has value and all timeslots are sold out, but the first one does not have a value which is "Choose a Time"
//Not sure if I need a loop at all. 
 productShowTimeListOption.each(function(){
    if($(this).val() != "" && $(this).hasClass("timeSoldOut")){
       console.log("productTimeList has sold out times.");  
    }
});

 //Need to know if all of the actual time lists are sold out and ignore the
 // "Choose a time" option in order to trigger message that all the times are sold out. 
  //THIS ONE IS NOT QUITE WORKING STILL GETTING NOT SOLD OUT.
  //if any of time time lists options have a time value but does not have the class of time slot sold out
if(productShowTimeListOption.val() != "" && !productShowTimeListOption.hasClass("museumTimeSlotSoldOut").length){
    console.log("time list not sold out");
}else{
    console.log("all times are sold out");
}
```

HTML

```
<select name="TimesSelect" id="ShowTimeList">
     <option value="">Choose a Time</option>
                <option value="208292" disabled="disabled" class="timeSoldOut">10:50 AM - SOLD OUT</option>
                <option value="208464" disabled="disabled" class="timeSoldOut">11:00 AM - SOLD OUT</option>
                <option value="208636" disabled="disabled" class="timeSoldOut">11:10 AM - SOLD OUT</option>
                <option value="208808" disabled="disabled" class="timeSoldOut">11:20 AM - SOLD OUT</option>
 </select
```

Comment: All options, that has "timeSoldOut" class and value is not null, I think this is the selector you need: `$('#ShowTimeList option.timeSoldOut[value!=""]')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe like this:

```js
if(!$('#ShowTimeList option[value!=""]').not('.timeSoldOut').length){
 alert('Time is over');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="TimesSelect" id="ShowTimeList">
     <option value="">Choose a Time</option>
     <option value="208292" disabled="disabled" class="timeSoldOut">10:50 AM - SOLD OUT</option>
     <option value="208464" disabled="disabled" class="timeSoldOut">11:00 AM - SOLD OUT</option>
     <option value="208636" disabled="disabled" class="timeSoldOut">11:10 AM - SOLD OUT</option>
     <option value="208808" disabled="disabled" class="timeSoldOut">11:20 AM - SOLD OUT</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: This takes into account the "Choose a time" option and if any times are available then it won't trigger?  Seemed like it ran correctly when I ran the snippet

Comment: This one worked.  Just wasn't getting all the 'nots' correct.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a jQuery selector to find all the options in the list that have a value and don't have the timeSoldOut class applied. Then check the length to see if there are any items.

Here is a quick example:

```js
console.log($('#ShowTimeList option[value!=""]:not(.timeSoldOut)'))
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<select name="TimesSelect" id="ShowTimeList">
     <option value="">Choose a Time</option>
                <option value="208292" disabled="disabled" class="timeSoldOut">10:50 AM - SOLD OUT</option>
                <option value="208464" disabled="disabled" class="timeSoldOut">11:00 AM - SOLD OUT</option>
                <option value="208636" disabled="disabled" class="timeSoldOut">11:10 AM - SOLD OUT</option>
                <option value="208808" disabled="disabled" class="timeSoldOut">11:20 AM - SOLD OUT</option><option value="208808" disabled="disabled" >11:20 AM</option>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

All options, that has "timeSoldOut" class and value is not null, this can be done with this selector: `$('#ShowTimeList option.timeSoldOut[value!=""]')`

```js
$('#ShowTimeList option.timeSoldOut[value!=""]').each(function () {
   console.log($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="TimesSelect" id="ShowTimeList">
     <option value="">Choose a Time</option>
     <option value="208292" disabled="disabled" class="timeSoldOut">10:50 AM - SOLD OUT</option>
     <option value="208464" disabled="disabled" class="timeSoldOut">11:00 AM - SOLD OUT</option>
     <option value="208636" disabled="disabled" class="timeSoldOut">11:10 AM - SOLD OUT</option>
     <option value="208808" disabled="disabled" class="timeSoldOut">11:20 AM - SOLD OUT</option>
 </select>
```